# Looking for TTS (Text To Speech) offline software with both Windows/Linux support

Tags: windows, gratis, offline, speech-synthesis, accessibility

I am looking for **freeware** TTS (Text To Speech) software for **Windows** or **Paid Software** (no subscription), which has also **Linux support**,
as I will switch to Linux later! I just need something which will work... *It is very hard to find and I have chronic pain, thank for understanding!*

**It has to be offline program!**

**Should have:**

1. Price range: up to 100$
2. no pauses after end of lines
3. text should stretch to whole screen (so I can copy paste text to my .doc to make notes)
4. should be able to read pdf file: the more file types the better! *(dislike annoying copy paste + in my PDF reader scrolling is so slow)*
5. use of hotkeys
6. speed adjusment

**I tried:**

balabolka, or panopreter but it is bad/buggy...